# Twitter's Bootstrap 2.x navbar overflows to 2 rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a simple navbar with 3 textual links, a search bar and a dropdown with more links, as seen in the jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/guyisra/DByTm/1/

[full window fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guyisra/DByTm/1/embedded/result/) (resize window until 2 rows)

```
<div class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top ">
    <div class="navbar-inner " style="padding:3px;">
        <div class="container navbar_container" style=" margin-left: 50px; "> <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
    <a class="brand" href="/" style=" padding: 0; width: 185px; ">
             LOGO
             <div class="sprite-logos "></div>

            </a>

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse ">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li id="loading-indicator" style="margin-top: 8px; visibility: hidden;">
                        <div></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li class="nav_option"><a href="/Link1"><i class="icon-envelope"> </i> Link num 1 </a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="nav_option"><a href="/Link2"><i class="icon-envelope"> </i> Link num 2</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/Link3"><i class="icon-envelope"> </i> Link num 3</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/home" class="navbar-search pull-left" method="get">
                        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
                            <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
                        </div>  <span class="icon-search" style="position:relative;vertical-align: middle;left:27px;"></span>

                        <input class="input-medium search-query" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Search" required="required" style="padding-left:29px" type="text">
                    </form>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <div>   <a href="/red" class="btn btn-danger">RED</a>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Jimmy bob
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/Link"><i class="icon-envelope"> </i> Link</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/Link"><i class="icon-envelope"> </i> Link</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/Link"><i class="icon-envelope"> </i> Link</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li> <a href="/Link"><i class="icon-envelope"> </i> Link</a> 
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li> <a href="Link" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow"><i class="icon-envelope"> </i> Link</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  <span class="sprite_loader"></span>

</div>
```

when resizing, one of the sizes causing the nabvar to shift and make 2 rows, as in the picture below

[image]

I can't shorten Link1,2,3 name, and the user's name could be longer.

I'd like the navbar to always be 1 row, and that if the user name (or the pull-right part) is too long to push the search form to be shorter

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `row` in a `container` is the best practice while using Twitter Bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        // your content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good suggestion. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html don't use it for the navbar.

Comment: @BassJobsen Yes interestingly they don't use in the documentation too. This is just a real-life experiment.

Answer (score 0):

In your case / example add a span2 class to your search input field: see http://jsfiddle.net/bassjobsen/s9Mcp/1/

```
<input class="span2 input-medium search-query" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Search" required="required" style="padding-left:29px" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue seemed to be that I just had too much stuff in the nav bar. Lots of buttons, search form, logo, etc, made it much larger than ~940px, so it folded to two rows before reaching the trigger width (940px) for collapsing. Not sure if there is a way to accommodate this, but I decided to just remove some buttons, shorten some text, etc, and that got me past it.